# System.Web.HttpException: 'A field or property with the name 'DOB' was not found on the selected data source.'

Tags: c#, asp.net

//Asp.net Code Section
**ASPX Code which i have written already:-**

```
'''<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="mobile" HeaderText="mobile" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="address" HeaderText="address" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="DOB" HeaderText="DOB" />
<asp:TemplateField>
<itemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="Linkview" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("contactID")%>' OnClick="lnk_onClick">View</asp:LinkButton>
</itemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>'''
```

//C# Code Section
**Code logic i made to work behind the scene:-**

```
'''void FillGridView()
{
if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
     sqlCon.Open();
SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("ContactViewAll",sqlCon);
sqlDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
sqlCon.Close();
gvcontact.DataSource = dtbl;
gvcontact.DataBind();
}'''
```

Comment: Your stored procedure does not return a column `DOB`

Comment: Execute your stored procedure and check is SP returning DOB or not ?

Comment: yup its done there was a spelling mistake in DB

Comment: Thanks to the community!